# Binary Number Having same number of 0s and 1s

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

Given a binary string or a binary number(one is free to take it in any way), I need to find out the next smaller binary number but retaining the number of 0s and 1s in the original binary string or number.

For e.g.

> If the given binary number or string was 11100000, the required output would be 11010000.
>
> If the given binary number or string was 11010000, the required output would be 11001000.

Of course, I can do this with Brute Force approach. But I needed a better solution. What could be an optimal way of doing it? I was wondering if someone can help me reach a solution to this in O(1) using bit wise operations.

Comment: You have same input twice, and two different outputs. Please fix this.

Comment: You have two different outputs using the same input.  Is there some other input or is the first/second input number incorrect?

Comment: What do you have so far? This looks somewhat like a homework (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: There are situations where this cannot be solved take for example 11.

Comment: There's definitely a way to do this if floor division counts as a "bitwise operation" (might have seen it in Hacker's Delight), but I'm disinclined to post it if brute force is really your best attempt.

Comment: if the input was 10, should the output be 01? Or are leading zeroes not allowed?

Comment: It's not always possible, and in any case it's not possible in O(1) in any meaningful sense (why should bitwise operators be O(1) when the problem size is the bit length?) That said, @Setzer22 had an answer that was close, and was only missing one bit: after you find the bit to shift right, you have to shift all `1` bits to the right of that as far left as they will go.

Comment: @pyStarter Not a homework problem.. some problem i was trying to solve in a more optimal way..turns out..if I can do this optiamlly..may be that one also I can do optimally

Comment: @Patrick87 The laws of physics do not apply to the unit-cost RAM, which is more or less the standard machine model that people consider for these types of problems.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat What RAM system, practical or theoretical, can perform bitwise operations on strings of arbitrary length in O(1)? Perhaps I'm just being a pedant, but the question might be better rendered "how can it be done for bit strings of the word length using a fixed number of instructions"? That might better capture the intent, if that is the intent.

Comment: @Patrick87 That's the conventional interpretation. I agree that your wording is clearer, and it's close to how I would have phrased the question if it were my ask.

Comment: Exchange the rightmost 1 that is still left of the rightmost 0 with the leftmost 0 to its right.

Comment: If this isn't homework, I'm the Pope/Flying Spaghetti Monster/Dalai Llama (insert favourite deity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an elaboration on Setzer22's answer, which was close but which lacked one vital piece.

```
FindNextSmallestWithSameNumberOfBits(string[1...n])
1. for i = n - 1  to 1 do
2.     if string[i+1] = 0 and string[i] = 1 then
3.         string[i] := 0
4.         string[i+1] := 1
5.         sort(string[i+2...n], descending)
6.         return string[1...n]
7. return "no solution"
```

This is an `O(n)` algorithm, which is a provably optimal asymptotic bound for this problem when the input size is unrestricted; while this is "bitwise" in the sense that it operates on bits, it clearly doesn't use what one would typically think of as "bitwise operations." Luckily, for inputs which can be of arbitrary length, there can be no asymptotic advantage to using traditional "bitwise operations" over this method. For inputs of fixed length, to which asymptotic analysis does not readily apply, one might do better using a technique such as those linked to by Asuka in the other answer to this question.

Note, based on comments, that sorting on line 5 can be replaced with simply reversing the string. The reason for this is that this substring is guaranteed to be of the form `0...01...1` (that is, any `0`s to the left of any `1`s) since, if it weren't, we'd have already found an occurrence of the string `10` and satisfied the condition on line 2.

The key that was missing in Setzer22's answer is that, once you move the rightmost `1` with a `0` to the right of it to the right, you then need to left-shift all the `1`s that are even further right as far left as they will go. The reason for this is that the `1` bit shifted to the right is more significant than the bits to the right of it, so left-shifting any `1`s which are less significant will give a larger number, but not large enough to undo the effect of reducing the more significant bit.

Clarification based on comments: notice that in line 7 of the pseudocode presented above, it's possible that the algorithm won't return a valid string. The reason for this is that, sometimes, there is no string with the same number of `1`s which represents a smaller number. This occurs if and only if the string `01` does not appear as a substring in the input string (in which case the condition on line 2 is never satisfied).

This isn't the clearest explanation of all time, so please let me know if it needs more work. Here's an example:

```
10011 // input
01011 // right-shift the right-most 1 bit with a 0 to the right of it
01110 // left-shift all 1 bits to the right of the right-shifted as far as possible

1010100011 // input
1010010011 // right-shift the right-most 1 bit with a 0 to the right of it
1010011100 // left-shift all 1 bits to the right of the right-shifted bit as far as possible
```

One way to clarify this which just occurred to me: right-shifting the `1` bit guarantees that the result will be smaller than the original number; left-shifting the `1`s to the right guarantees that the result will no smaller than is necessary.

Comment: Also,you must clarify OP that this is not possible for some binary String which consists of only 0's or only 1's!

Comment: @shekharsuman Good point, this is good to clarify.

Comment: Instead of sorting, we can simply reverse, right?

Comment: @ankitG Yes, of course you're right: reversing will be equivalent since the string must be of the form `0...01...1`. Otherwise, we would have found an occurrence of `10` earlier. Noting this.

Comment: So, whats the efficiency of this solution. O(n^2)? Right? Can we do better?

Comment: @ankitG It's O(n). At worst, you first look through the whole string, then reverse the whole string. Both are O(n), and adding them is O(n). Note that you never have to reverse the string more than once. This is theoretically optimal for the problem when it's not restricted to binary strings of a certain length. As David points out in his comments on the question, when values are restricted (e.g., to 32 bit words), you can indeed do better than this using, e.g., the kinds of ugly hacks that Asuka links to in the other answer.

Comment: @ankitG Note also how this compares to the (what I assume you mean by) "brute-force" solution. The number of steps in that method works in terms of the number represented, rather than the number of bits in the representation, and I would therefore not be surprised if the complexity of that turned out to be exponential, i.e., O(2^n).

Comment: To whomever downvoted this: please feel free to let me know how this answer could be improved. Otherwise, no hard feelings, of course.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I'm a bit disappointed that it was selected as the answer since the question specifically asked if it could be done with bitwise operations.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's a fair criticism based on the question as it is now, although the phrasing of the original question suggests that this wasn't the asker's real intent. It looks like the first edit changed the meaning of the question slightly in this regard. I'll go ahead and roll that part of the question back so that it is more in line with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are finding:

https://github.com/hcs0/Hackers-Delight/blob/master/snoob.c.txt

The functions `snoob()`, `snoob1()`, `snoob2()`, `snoob3()`, `snoob4()` and `next_set_of_n_elements()` are various implementations.

These functions are helper functions which are called by the above functions:

- `ntz()` stands for "number of trailing zeros"
- `nlz()` stands for "number of leading zeros"
- `pop()` stands for "population count" (number of bit set (number of "1"s) in the string)

This is very efficient but only works on fix size integers (eg 32-bit, 64-bit).

Comment: Difficult Read. Can you explain a bit? Whats the efficiency? O(n) ?

Comment: @ankitG A cursory inspection suggests these only support fixed-size inputs - 32 bits, apparently. It doesn't make much sense to discuss asymptotic performance for inputs which cannot grow arbitrarily large. If this restriction were removed, and bitwise arithmetic were implemented in such a way that it would work with arbitrary-length input, then yes, it would be O(n) since any bitwise operator would need to inspect the values of all O(n) bits, though presumably not much more than that.

Comment: @ankitG So what is the type of your input and what is the programming language you use? I assumed you are working on fix size integers (eg. 32-bit, 64-bit) and using a C-style language (eg. C, C++, Java, Objective-C, etc). It is surely difficult to read, since it is black magic of bit-twiddling. But someone who is more experienced in optimization will tell you that "Hacker's Delight" algorithms work!

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- Yeah! Dats correct. I use C#,Java,C,C++(sometimes). Input actually is implementation dependent. That's why I wrote one is free to take it as a binary number or as a binary string.

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- Can you compare your solution with the one given by Patrick87? Can you say that yours is better (with reasons of course)? It might surely work but for the same kind of performance, why would I not go for a solution simpler to read and understand?

Comment: @ankitG If your bit string is arbitrarily long, then you can divide it into fix size "units". For example, if your input is 72-bit long, and if you are using 32-bit units, then you can divide it into 3 units: a-b-c, a being 8-bit, b being 32-bit and c being 32-bit. Then if you need a 3-bit-set string, apply the Hacker's Delight algorithm like this: (a:0, b:0, c:3), (a:0, b:1, c:2), (a:0, b:2, c:1), (a:0, b:3, c:0), and so on... But I think this destroys your original purpose of performance, since "separating the number into buckets" is similar to your original problem...